# uanble to compare times before and after midnight

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to compare times before and after midnight however after midnight the check fails.

What I want to do is check if the time is between 11 pm and 6 am.

Here is what I'm working with

```js
// Hours
const start =  23 * 60 + 0;
const end   =   6 * 60 + 0;

// Get todays date 11pm
const now = new Date();

// Check tomorrow for 6am
const nextDay = new Date(now.getTime() + 86400000); 

const time_today = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();
const time_tomorrow = nextDay.getHours() * 60 + nextDay.getMinutes();

if (time_today >= start && time_tomorrow < end) {
    return interaction.reply({content: `You cannot do that until 6am.`, ephemeral: true})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `now.getHours()`, why not just check if it's between 11pm and 6 am?

```js
const hours = now.getHours();
if (hours < 6 || hours==23){
  return interaction.reply({content: `You cannot do that until 6am.`, ephemeral: true});
}
```